# LINQ to Entities and SQL Injection

Tags: security, linq-to-entities, sql-injection

I've seen a couple of conflicting articles about whether or not L2E is susceptible to SQL injection.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760.aspx):

> Although query composition is possible in LINQ to Entities, 
>   it is performed through the object model API. Unlike Entity SQL queries, 
>   LINQ to Entities queries are not composed by using string manipulation 
>   or concatenation, and they are not susceptible to traditional SQL
>   injection attacks.

Does that imply that there are "non-traditional" attacks that may work?  [This article](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/linq-to-entities-entity-sql-parameterized-store-queries-and-sql-injection/) has one example of a non-parameterized query - is it safe to assume that if you pass in user-supplied data via a variable it will be parameterized?

If I do:

```
from foo in ctx.Bar where foo.Field = userSuppliedString select foo;
```

am I safe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example you're using a variable (`userSuppliedString`), so it will be parameterized.

If you had a literal value in your code:

```
from foo in ctx.Bar where foo.Field == "Hi" select foo;
```

...then EF 1 won't parameterize it, but there's also zero danger of SQL injection since it's a literal.

Answer (score 3):

Good luck trying to get anyone to tell you that a certain piece of code does not have a certain security vulnerability. That being said, I personally would not be concerned about SQL Injection attacks through a LINQ query vector (unless I was doing something very bizarre behind-the-scenes).