# EntitySQL and SQL injection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-injection, entity-sql

I've got the following query string

```
"SELECT VALUE entity FROM Entities AS entity WHERE entity.Client_id
= 0 && entity.Name LIKE @searchvalue ORDER BY @sorting SKIP @skip LIMIT @limit"
```

with the following param replacement

```
query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("skip", start));
query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("limit", limit));
query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("searchvalue", searchValue + "%"));
query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("sorting", sortField + " " + sortDirection.ToUpper()));
```

But I always end up in the exception:

> The key expression 'ORDER BY' must have at least one reference to the
>   immediate input scope. Near ORDER BY clause item

I guess this happends cause `query.Parameters.Add(...)` wraps all in quotes? I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194848/linq-to-entities-and-sql-injection) but for what benefit then do I need `query.Parameters.Add(...)` if nothing can happens? OK, the attacker may not start a new query but I guess he can manipulate the current?

Comment: Not familiar with entity-sql, but my guess is yes, it thinks that, e.g. `fieldname asc` is the name of the field you want. Can you try with `... ORDER BY @sortfield @sortdir ...` and using two parms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess: 
The first thing I would try it to do something like this

> SELECT VALUE entity FROM Entities AS entity WHERE entity.Client_id
>   = 0 && entity.Name LIKE '@searchvalue' ORDER BY @sorting @sortorder SKIP @skip LIMIT @limit

```
query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("searchvalue", searchValue + "%"));
query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("sorting",   sortField ));
query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("sortorder", sortDirection));
```

In other words: move *sorting order* to seprated parameter.

**EDIT**

If this doesn't work use [Query Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896238.aspx) to construct a query.

Look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6b95ad32-6642-4ec7-8051-e0bdfe022eff/) for example.

Good luck.

Comment: that was my initial one... So no, that result in the same error

Comment: @sra: ok, so probably it's a worst case, when you can not do this. But it should be possible to do with ObjectQuery builder. Look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6b95ad32-6642-4ec7-8051-e0bdfe022eff/)

Comment: that is the answer! You should copy that at the bottom of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried removing the quotes @searchvalue, since you are using a parameterized query IMO, quotes are no longer required.

Instead of:

```
"SELECT VALUE entity FROM Entities AS entity WHERE entity.Client_id
= 0 && entity.Name LIKE '@searchvalue' ORDER BY @sorting SKIP @skip LIMIT @limit"
```

Try this:

```
"SELECT VALUE entity FROM Entities AS entity WHERE entity.Client_id
= 0 && entity.Name LIKE @searchvalue ORDER BY @sorting SKIP @skip LIMIT @limit"
```

Comment: I've forgot these, you're absolutely right. But nonetheless that's not my error... I've fixed this in my post. But does parameterized query automatic quote?

Comment: It will automatically apply the quotes if necessary (e.g. when working with strings). There's no need to wrap a parameter in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use parameters as replacement of column names.